# show inherited multiple containers of the same pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this, show

I want to show the hidden div content in the "hidden" by clicking on the text view answer. but does not work, only the first is shown.

when clicking on the second the first is shown.

What is the correct way?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#script").ready(function(){
        $(".click",this).click(function(){
            $("#oculto").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
});

</script>

<div id="script">
    Cear una variable e imprimir su contenido.<br>
    <b class="click">Ver respuesta</b>
    <br><br>
    <div id="oculto">
        TEXT ONE
    </div>
</div>


<div id="script">
    Cear una variable e imprimir su contenido.<br>
    <b class="click">Ver respuesta</b>
    <br><br>
    <div id="oculto">
        TEXT TWO
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the differences between `id` and `class`? Do you know when it is appropriate to us an `id`, and when you should use `class`?

Comment: no, the truth is I do not really know the difference, but I combined a few things and I can not fix it. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The code you submitted uses `id` in both `<div id="script">`. `id` is supposed to be used once per page, where a `class` may be used more than once. If you switch from:

```
<div id="script">
```

to

```
<div class="script">
```

and also do the same for `oculto`

and then change your selectors from `$("#script")` and `$("#oculto")` to use `.` instead of `#` like $(".script") then you will be one step closer to having things work.

There are other problems with the sample code, but this was the most glaring. You also likely need to fix your use of `$("#script").ready(function(){`. Stop and attempt to explain to yourself what that line is doing.

Comment: 're right, that line does not make much sense, I wanted was that clicking on "click" was a reference to "script" to indicate that you are referring to and had no errors when selecting the div.

Comment: solution and thank for jason aller.

    <script>
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#script .click").click(function(){
      var ev = $(this).parent("#script");
      ev.find('.oculto').slideToggle("slow");
     });
    });
    
    </script>